# group by day and another field in presto

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to group both by day (my times are in unix epoch) and name that gives me the score times the multiplier.

My table looks like this:

```
time             | name    | score | multiplier
1646733600000000 | Albert  | 10    | 1
1646744400000000 | John    | 5     | 1.5
1646780400000000 | John    | 3     | 2.2
1646812800000000 | Albert  | 7     | 1.1
1646816400000000 | Marie   | 26    | 0.5
1646852400000000 | Marie   | 1     | 2.2
1646870400000000 | Georgie | 30    | 0.75
1646924400000000 | Georgie | 2     | 0.5
1646938800000000 | Kevin   | 15    | 0.3
```

The result would be:

```
day        | name    | score * multiplier
2022-03-08 | Albert  | 10 * 1
2022-03-08 | John    | (5 * 1.5) + (3 * 2.2)
2022-03-09 | Albert  | 7 * 1.1
2022-03-09 | Marie   | (26 * 0.5) + (1 * 2.2)
2022-03-10 | Georgie | (30 * 0.75) + (2 * 0.5)
2022-03-10 | Kevin   | 15 * 0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be simple enough - the main trick is to divide timestamp by 1000000 to have it in seconds and not microseconds:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (time, name, score, multiplier) AS (
    VALUES
    (1646733600000000,  'Albert', 10,    1),
    (1646744400000000,  'John', 5 ,    1.5),
    (1646780400000000,  'John', 3 ,    2.2),
    (1646812800000000,  'Albert', 7 ,    1.1),
    (1646816400000000,  'Marie', 26,    0.5),
    (1646852400000000,  'Marie', 1 ,    2.2),
    (1646870400000000,  'Georgie', 30,    0.75),
    (1646924400000000,  'Georgie', 2 ,    0.5),
    (1646938800000000,  'Kevin', 15,    0.3)
) 

--query
select date(from_unixtime(time/1000000)) day, name, sum(score*multiplier) "score * multiplier" 
from dataset
group by 1, name -- or date(from_unixtime(time/1000000)) instead of 1
order by 1, name -- for output order
```

Output:

| day | name | score * multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 | Albert | 10.0 |
| 2022-03-08 | John | 14.100000000000001 |
| 2022-03-09 | Albert | 7.700000000000001 |
| 2022-03-09 | Marie | 15.2 |
| 2022-03-10 | Georgie | 23.5 |
| 2022-03-10 | Kevin | 4.5 |